# How can I check the input from a message box's buttons in Python using the ctypes library?

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to store the input from a dialog box with the `ctypes` library:

```
import ctypes
def mbox(message, title, style):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(message, title, style)

mbox("This is a message box test", "Message Box", 1)
```

The style is, of course, an OK and a Cancel button. How do I take the input from when you click on one of the buttons and then split into a separate function or something, such as:

```
if [Insert said check here]:
    mbox("You pressed OK!", "Answer", 0)
else:
    mbox("You pressed Cancel!", "Answer", 0)
```

Comment: You need to catch the return value of the message box and return it from `mbox`

Answer (score 0):

Provide the style `MB_OKCANCEL` to the `MessageBox` and test its return value. You can find the numerical values in the [MessageBox function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
import ctypes
class MbConstants:
    MB_OKCANCEL = 1
    IDCANCEL = 2
    IDOK = 1

def mbox(message, title):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0,message, title, MbConstants.MB_OKCANCEL)

rc = mbox("message","title")
if  rc == MbConstants.IDOK:
    print("ok")
elif rc == MbConstants.IDCANCEL:
    print("cancel")
```

Comment: Don't confuse MessageBoxes with MassageBoxes... they just massage people instead of displaying dialog. Also, how do you perform the same action with different styles, do you use stuff like `IDABORT` or `IDRETRY` etc.?

Comment: Yes. The return value is the id of the pressed button.